# linux merge rows if Columns less than X

Tags: linux, awk, sed, merge, row

I need you support in creating the output.
I have output as

```
1  ABC  STATUS       
   7    PROHIBITED   
   8    PROHIBITED   
2  CDE  STATUS       
   7    PROHIBITED   
   8    PROHIBITED   
3  FGH  STATUS       
   142  PROHIBITED   
2  HIJ  STATUS       
   7    PROHIBITED
```

I am trying to achieve as

```
`1  ABC  STATUS      7      PROHIBITED   8      PROHIBITED   
2  CDE  STATUS       7    PROHIBITED   8    PROHIBITED   
3  FGH  STATUS       142  PROHIBITED   
2  HIJ  STATUS       7      PROHIBITED
```

OR Either below where every first and second column is filled in below empty gaps.

```
`1  ABC  STATUS      
1  ABC   7      PROHIBITED   
1  ABC   8      PROHIBITED   
2  CDE  STATUS       
2  CDE   7    PROHIBITED   
2  CDE  8    PROHIBITED   
3  FGH  STATUS       
3  FGH   142  PROHIBITED   
2  HIJ  STATUS       
2  HIJ    7     PROHIBITED   
2  HIJ    8     PROHIBITED   `
```

so far I have tried to achieve this in one single row with

```
cat file | paste -sd'\t\n'
```

but it is not showing the result as expected. it would be appreciated if any one can provide me with guidance as to how to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `awk` idea for generating the first set of output:

```
awk '
    { if (NF==3)
         printf "%s%s",(NR>1 ? "\n" : ""),$0        # if not 1st row of input then prefix the output with "\n" (to terminate previous line of output)
      else      
         printf "%s",$0
    }
END {print ""}                                      # terminate last line of output
' file
```

This generates:

```
1  ABC  STATUS   7    PROHIBITED   8    PROHIBITED
2  CDE  STATUS   7    PROHIBITED   8    PROHIBITED
3  FGH  STATUS   142  PROHIBITED
2  HIJ  STATUS   7    PROHIBITED   8    PROHIBITED
```

Comment: Thanks, dear. I didn't thought of using the column number (NF==3)

Comment: I had tried and used  as `awk '{if (NF>2) {p1=$1;p2=$2;print}else{print p1" "p2" "$0}}`

Answer (score 2):

Using any POSIX awk you can just test if a line starts with a space or not:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", (/^[[:space:]]/ ? "" : sep), $0; sep=ORS} END{print ""}' file
1  ABC  STATUS          7    PROHIBITED      8    PROHIBITED
2  CDE  STATUS          7    PROHIBITED      8    PROHIBITED
3  FGH  STATUS          142  PROHIBITED
2  HIJ  STATUS          7    PROHIBITED
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following GNU `awk` code.

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)[0-9]+' -v OFS="\t" '
RT && FNR>1{
  gsub(/\n/,"")
  $1=$1
  print
}
END{
  if($0){
    gsub(/^ +|\n/,"")
    $1=$1
    print
  }
}
'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

If lines to be joined always begin with blanks as in the sample input, then a `sed` solution could be

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n\([[:blank:]]\)/\1/;ta' -e 'P;D' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\S/{:a;x;s/\n//gp;d};H;$!d;ba' file
```

Store records in the hold space and at the start of a new record or the end of the file, swap back to the hold space, remove any newlines and print.

N.B. A new record is designated by a non-white space character at the start of a line.